# ¿Cómo obtener fecha actual con formato ISO 8601 con hora fija en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

Me encuentro con un inconveniente que por el momento no logro solucionar, mi código es el siguiente:

```
const tiempoTranscurrido = Date.now();
const hoy = new Date(tiempoTranscurrido);
console.log(hoy.toISOString());
```

Con el cuál obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
2022-11-29T22:45:56.371Z
```

Lo que estoy necesitando es que el resultado salga de la siguiente forma:

```
2022-11-29T03:00:00.000Z
```

Es decir, que la fecha sea la actual pero que la hora sea siempre T03:00:00.000Z independientemente de la hora actual. Hasta el momento no logro conseguirlo, ¿Cómo podría conseguirlo?

Comment: No se ver la diferencia... ¿no es lo mismo?

Comment: @masterguru la diferencia es que me debería devolver la fecha actual seguida de T03:00:00.00Z, independientemente de la hora actual

Comment: No es lo mismo lo que has puesto en el comentario que lo que hay en la pregunta. En el comentario tienes un 0 menos.  Pero si eso no es importante, y siempre quieres que sea T03:00:00.000Z saca entonces solo la fecha actual, por ejemplo, `2022-11-29` y le concatenas esa cadena `T03:00:00.000Z`, ¿no?

Comment: @masterguru, es una alternativa, en ese caso debería obtener la fecha en el formato 2022-11-29 y de ahí la concateno con T03:00:00.000Z

Comment: O sea, ¿quieres esto?  `console.log(hoy.toISOString().split("T")[0] + 'T03:00:00.000Z')`

Comment: @masterguru exacto, da el resultado que necesito, muchas gracias!

Comment: Vale, espera que lo pongo en la respuesta... aunque no entiendo porque quieres prefijar la hora, tus motivos tendras.

Comment: Pues ya tienes una respuesta funcional :-)  Si es realmente lo que buscas recuerda marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente eternamente, gracias!

Comment: @masterguru pasa que esa fecha la utilizo para comparar con unas fechas de unas tablas de una base de datos, la base de datos MariaDB me devuelve siempre la fecha actual seguida de T03:00:00.000Z

Comment: Si, claro, ahora lo entiendo... lo que no comprendia al principio era que pensaras que eran dos formatos de fecha distinta, pero no era eso, sino que pretendias prefijarla.

Comment: @masterguru tienes razón, no me expresé bien con la pregunta, ahí editaré la publicación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres, segun los comentarios, es prefijar la fecha actual a esa hora en ese formato, lo más practico seria dividir la hora con `split()` en la letra **T** para luego concatenar la hora prefijada, de este modo:

```js
const tiempoTranscurrido = Date.now();
const hoy = new Date(tiempoTranscurrido);
console.log(hoy.toISOString().split("T")[0] + 'T03:00:00.000Z')
```